# In spring mvc java, how to convert form values to json and then submit to rest controller from jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring, rest

I've been trying from last three days. I'm not getting how to convert form values into json and then pass it to spring mvc rest controller.Please help me with this.

here is script :

$(function() {
     $('#formId').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault(); // prevent this form from being submited
        var userJson = JSON.stringify(jQuery('#formId').serializeArray());
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Owner/addprop",
            data: userJson,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                 alert(data);//handle it in a proper way
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
               alert(errMsg);//handle it in a proper way
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});

here is my form :

```
<springform:form method="post" action="" commandName="property" id="formId"
 name="myform" >


    <div class="section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">







                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Property/House No:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_houseno">
                                <input name="property_houseno" class="form-control" type="text"
                                     value="${hno}" id="property_houseno" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo4" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_houseno" cssClass="error" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span> Location<i style="color: red;">*</i> <spring:bind
                                    path="property.property_loc">
                                    <div id="locationField">
                                        <input id="autocomplete" name="property_loc"
                                            placeholder="Search for location" onFocus="geolocate()"
                                            type="text" class="form-control" value="${locn}" required></input>
                                    </div>
                                </spring:bind>
                                <p id="demo6" cssClass="error" /> <springform:errors
                                    path="property_loc" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            street Name:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_streetname">
                                <input name="property_streetname" class="form-control"
                                    value="${stname}" id="route" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo5" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_streetname" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span>Pincode </span><i style="color: red;">*</i>
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_pin">
                                <input name="property_pin" class="form-control"
                                    id="postal_code" pattern="[0-9]{6}" value="${pcode}"
                                    title="Pincode should contain 6 digitis" required />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo7" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_pin" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            City:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_city">
                                <input path="property_city" class="form-control"
                                    name="property_city" type="text" value="${cit}" id="locality" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo8" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_city" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            State:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_state">
                                <input path="property_state" class="form-control"
                                    name="property_state" type="text" value="${state}"
                                    id="administrative_area_level_1" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo9" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_state" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Area:
                            <spring:bind path="property.subarea">
                                <input path="subarea" class="form-control" name="subarea"
                                    type="text" value="${area}" id="sublocality_level_1" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo9" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="subarea" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Country:
                            <spring:bind path="property.country">
                                <input path="country" class="form-control" name="country"
                                    value="${cntry}" type="text" id="country" />
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo9" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="country" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset style="border: 1px solid silver; padding: 30px">
                        <legend class="text-center">Property Details</legend>
                        <div class="col-md-6" >
                            Property Type:<i style="color: red;">*</i>
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_type">
                                <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                    <select name="property_type" onchange="setSubProp()" onload="setSubProp()" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_type" required>

                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                                        <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>


                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </spring:bind>
                        <%--    <p id="demo1" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_type" cssClass="error" /> --%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" id="resi_sub_cat">
                            Property Type(Sub Category):<i style="color: red;">*</i>
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_type_sub">
                                <div id="pts" style="display: block">
                                    <select name="property_type_sub" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_type_sub1" >

                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="Apartment">Apartment</option>
                                        <option value="Independent">Independent</option>
                                        <option value="Row House">Row House</option>
                                        <option value="Twin House">Twin House</option>
                                        <option value="Bungalow">Bungalow</option>
                                        <option value="Farmhouse">Farmhouse</option> -->

                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo1" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_type" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <%-- <div class="col-md-6" id="comm_sub_cat">
                            Property Type(Sub Category):<i style="color: red;">*</i>
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_type_sub">
                                <div id="pdi12" style="display: block">
                                    <select name="property_type_sub" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_type_sub2" >

                                        <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="Office">Office</option>
                                        <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
                                        <option value="Leisure">Leisure</option>
                                        <option value="Industrial">Industrial</option>


                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo1" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_type" cssClass="error" />
                        </div> --%>
                        <%-- <div class="col-md-6">
                            Status<i style="color: red;">*</i>&nbsp; <a href="#"
                                data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                title="<b>For sell</b> : Selecting &#8220;for sell&#8221;, property will be published for sell. This means property will show-up in search results when user search for property which are on sale. Property will show-up if any of search parameters match.
                         <br /> <br />   <b>For rent</b> : Selecting &#8220;for rent&#8221; property will be published for rent. This property will show-up in search results of properties on rent,only if its on lease. Adding lease will enable the user to provide the lease details like rent amount, bond amount etc.
```

**none** : Select “none” if you are unsure about you wish to sell or rent this property. You can change the property status at any point of time."
                                    class="my_tooltip">" />

```
                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_status">
                                    <select name="property_status" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_status" onchange="setDyna()" required>
                                        <option value="">select</option>
                                        <option value="for Rent">for Rent</option>
                                        <option value="for Sale">for Sell</option>
                                        <option value="none">None</option>

                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>

                            </div>
                            <p id="demo15" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_status" cssClass="error" />
                        </div> --%>




                        <div class="col-md-6" id="bedrum">
                            Bedrooms<i style="color: red;">*</i>
                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_bedroom">
                                    <select name="property_bedroom" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_bedroom" >
                                        <option value="">select</option>

                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="studio apartment">Studio Apartment</option>
                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                            </div>

                            <p id="demo10" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_bedroom" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Parking Type<i style="color: red;">*</i>

                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_ptype">
                                    <select name="property_ptype" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_ptype" onchange="checkWheel();" required>
                                        <option value="">select</option>
                                        <option value="2 Wheeler">2 Wheeler</option>
                                        <option value="4 Wheeler">4 Wheeler</option>
                                        <option value="Both">Both</option>
                                        <option value="No Parking">No Parking</option>

                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                            </div>

                            <p id="demo14" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_ptype" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Parking Spaces<i style="color: red;">*</i>

                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_carspace">
                                    <select name="property_carspace" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_carspace" required>
                                        <option value="">select</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>
                                        <option value="0">0</option>
                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                            </div>

                            <p id="demo11" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_carspace" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Furnished<i style="color: red;">*</i>

                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_furnish">
                                    <select name="property_furnish" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_furnish" required>
                                        <option value="">select</option>
                                        <option value="Furnished">Furnished</option>
                                        <option value="Semi-Furnished">Semi-Furnished</option>
                                        <option value="Un-Furnished">Un-Furnished</option>

                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                            </div>

                            <p id="demo12" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_furnish" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Bathrooms<i style="color: red;">*</i>

                            <div id="pdi2" style="display: block">
                                <spring:bind path="property.property_bathrooms">
                                    <select name="property_bathrooms" class="form-control"
                                        id="property_bathrooms" required>
                                        <option value="">select</option>
                                        <option value="1">1</option>
                                        <option value="2">2</option>
                                        <option value="3">3</option>
                                        <option value="4">4</option>
                                        <option value="5">5</option>

                                    </select>
                                </spring:bind>
                            </div>

                            <p id="demo13" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_bathrooms" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-6" id="avb">
                            Property Available Date:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_availabledate">
                                <input name="property_availabledate" class="form-control"
                                    type="date" value="${adate}" id="property_availabledate" />
                            </spring:bind>

                            <p id="demo2" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_availabledate"
                                cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Property Registration no:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_regno">
                                <input name="property_regno" class="form-control" type="text"
                                    value="${pregno}" id="property_regno" />
                            </spring:bind>

                            <p id="demo2" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_regno" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Carpet Area:
                            <spring:bind path="property.sqft">
                                <input name="sqft" class="form-control" id="sqft"
                                    value="${bltparea}" pattern="[0-9]{2,10}" />
                            </spring:bind>

                            <p id="demo13" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="sqft" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <span>Please select a image to upload (Max 6 photos Max
                                size 5MB) : <a href="#" style="margin-bottom: 55;"
                                data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom"
                                title="Among the set of images which you select, the first selected image will be primary image. So select the images accordingly and upload"><img
                                    src="<c:url value="/resources/images/info-icon.png"/>" /></a>
                            </span>

                            <spring:bind path="property.file">
                                <input name="file" class="form-control" type="file" id="updf"
                                    accept="image/gif, image/jpeg" multiple
                                    onchange="checkSize()" />
                                <span class="style21"><springform:errors path="file"
                                        cssClass="error" /> </span>
                            </spring:bind>
                            <p id="demo13" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="file" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6" id="selling">
                            Property Selling Price:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_sellingprice">
                                <input name="property_sellingprice" class="form-control"
                                    type="text" value="${sellingp}" pattern="[0-9]{1,15}"
                                    title="Selling price should contain min. 1 and max.15 digits only."
                                    id="property_sellingprice" />
                            </spring:bind>

                            <p id="demo2" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="property_sellingprice" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Amenities&nbsp; <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                data-placement="bottom"
                                title="Press Ctrl key to select multiple Amenities"><img
                                src="<c:url value="/resources/images/info-icon.png"/>" /></a>

                            <spring:bind path="property.amenities">
                                <!--  <select name="amenities" class="form-control" id="property_status" onchange="setDyna()" required> -->
                                <select name="amenities" class="form-control" id="amenities"
                                    onchange="setDyna()" multiple>
                                    <option value="pool">Swimming Pool</option>
                                    <option value="park">Playground/park</option>
                                    <option value="gym">Gym/Fitness Center</option>
                                    <option value="security">Gate Security</option>
                                    <option value="club">Club House</option>
                                    <option value="intercom">Intercom</option>
                                    <option value="parking">Visitor Parking</option>
                                    <option value="lift">Lift</option>

                                </select>
                            </spring:bind>

                            <p id="demo15" cssClass="error" />
                            <springform:errors path="amenities" cssClass="error" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Description:
                            <spring:bind path="property.property_note">
                                <textarea name="property_note" class="form-control"
                                    id="property_note" value="${desc}" rows="4" cols="20">
                            </textarea>
                            </spring:bind>
                        </div>


                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-centered">
        <table class="table table-borderless">

            <td colspan="3"><div align="center">
                    <input type="Submit" class="btn btn-info" id="submit"
                        name="Submit" value="Submit" /> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input
                        type="reset" class="btn btn-info" name="Reset" value="Reset" />
                    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="button" name="b"
                        class="btn btn-info" value="Back" onclick="history.back();" />
                </div></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>



</springform:form>
```

I want to pass my jsp page to this rest controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addprop",method=RequestMethod.POST,headers="Accept=application/json" )
    public @ResponseBody PropRepo addpropr(@RequestBody PropRepo r, ModelMap map,HttpServletRequest request){


            pmService.addPerson(r);
            return r;


      }
```

Comment: return pmService.addPerson(r);

Comment: Thanks for replying Georges. But my question is, there is nothing wrong in controller, I'm asking how to  convert form values into json and then  send it to mentioned controller. Please see if you could help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441135/how-to-send-user-form-data-to-server-in-spring-mvc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send user form data to server in spring mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441135/how-to-send-user-form-data-to-server-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: Thanks for replying Kenz and oZOli.. I've tried but its not working.. form is not submitting to server. I'm not getting where I'm going wrong

Comment: Show how you are sending your form, please.

Comment: I've edited my question by sending full code of form and script iam using.. Tell me what where I'm going wrong please